# NDOC Error building documentation. 

Tags: c#, nant, ndoc

Using .NET Framework 3.5, I have nant -0.91-alpha2 which has support for framework 3.5 but I am getting the following error when I try to build the documentation.

> ```
> Error building Documentation.
>        Object reference not set to an instance of object.
>                Object reference not set to an instance of object
> ```

The documentation is to be generated by the following:

```
<target name="Documentation"> 
  <property name="nant.settings.currentframework" value="net-3.5"/> 
  <ndoc> 
    <assemblies> 
      <include name="Release\Project.dll" /> 
    </assemblies> 
    <summaries> 
      <include name="Release\Project.XML" /> 
    </summaries>
    <documenters> 
      <documenter name="MSDN"> //MSDN properties 
      </documenter> 
    </documenters> 
  </ndoc> 
</target>
```

Comment: <target name="Documentation">
    <property name="nant.settings.currentframework" value="net-3.5"/>
    <ndoc>
      <assemblies>
          <include name="Release\Project.dll" />
      </assemblies>
      <summaries>
           <include name="Release\Project.XML" />
      </summaries>
      <documenters>
        <documenter name="MSDN">   //MSDN properties
        </documenter>
      </documenters>
    </ndoc>
 </target>

Comment: What happens if you call the NDoc executable from the <exec> task?

Comment: Was the problem solved? I guess that the reason is that the assembly which should be documented contains generics ... (in this case I got the same exception)

Answer (score 0):

NDoc does not support .NET 3.5

Look at SandCastle

Comment: Info: Using NAnt 0.91 with net-4.0

Comment: Info2: When the assembly contains generics then SandCastle may be the better alternative since NAnt 0.92 still does not support generics and just fails with the exception mentioned by the original poster.